# Spring boot application Error 400 Bad request on POST

Tags: html, spring, http, post

I am trying to create a login form that posts 2 parameters (an email and a password). In my controller I am retrieving those parameters through `@RequestParam` . I've also specified that the method of this controller is `POST` in `@RequestMappig`. The problem is that I am getting 400 with the following message:

`Required String parameter 'email' is not present`

I've tried getting the params from `HttpServletRequest` and they are actually missing, but I have no clue why? Can anyone help me out please?

Here is my html :

```
<div id="form">
<form action="/authentication" method="post">
    <input type="email" value="Email" id="email" onfocus=labelsOnFocus(this) onblur=labelOnDefocus(this) onchange=emailErrorOnTyping(this)>
    <p id = "emailError">Email not valide</p>
    <input type="password" value="Password" id="password" onfocus=labelsOnFocus(this) onblur=labelOnDefocus(this) onchange=passwordErrorOnTyping(this)>
    <p id="passwordError">Password to short</p>
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit">
        <input type="button" value="Register" class="submit" onclick=register()>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is my controller:

```
public String authentication(@RequestParam("email") String email,@RequestParam("password") String password, Model model){

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("email",email);
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use form with `method="post"`, data send in post body, not in request params.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Comment: Ok then. So I should use @RequestBody to get the body. I assume that I can find the parameters values by looking for the form input ids,am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The `@RequestParam` annotation is for web request parameters not for the body of a POST. Try the `@RequestBody` parameter.

Also, consider using the `@ModelAttribute` in your HTML and controller method to bind the form body to a POJO ([see Baeldung's MVC Form tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial)).

Lastly, with Spring Boot you should not have to implement the `/authentication` controller yourself. If you `@EnableWebSecurity` and correctly wire up an `AuthenticationManager` with your `UserService` you should get authentication "for free" ([see Baeldung's Spring Security Tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login)).

Comment: Ok,thanks. I'll try it out. Also,I know that spring offers an  authentication controller with Security,but it seemed a bit complicated and I said for the moment I can implement my own

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way POST request works. When you do a post request then the data is sent in RequestBody, not in RequestParam. You can change your code as

```
public String authentication(@RequestBody Login login){

Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("email",login.email);
```

.....